# Get values from variable contents using PowerShell for code parsing

Tags: powershell, github, fileparsing

I have parsed the content of an API call to a variable $a.(Content below) and I would like to only parse out the list of packages which are under "dependencies". Is there are way to filter for only the dependencies using powershell?.

```
{
"name": "1package",
"version": "1.0.0",
"lockfileVersion": 1,
"requires": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": {
        "version": "7",
        "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org",
        "integrity": "***",
        "requires": {
            "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.4"
        }
    },
    "@cloud": {
        "version": "2",
        "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/",
        "integrity": "***"
    },
    "@cloudnative/health-connect": {
        "version": "2",
        "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@***.tgz",
        "integrity": "***",
        "requires": {
            "@cloudnative/health": "^2.1.1"
        }
    },
```

So I just want to parse out a list having

```
babel/runtime version 7
cloud version 2
cloudnative/health-connect version 2
```

Comment: I'd recommend, if it's a JSON, let's treat it as such: `.. | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Dependencies`.

Comment: Thanks alot. exactly what I wanted. it returns something like 

@actions/core         : @{version=1.2.6; resolved=https://registry.npmjs.org/@actions/core/-/core-1.2.6.tgz; 
                        integrity=sha512-ZQYitnqiyBc3D+k7LsgSBmMDVkOVidaagDG7j3fOym77jNunWRuYx7VSHa9GNfFZh+zh61xsCjRj4JxMZlDqTA==}.

what if I want it to return only the "version" and "resolved" property for each dependency. Thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By accessing the [`PSObject.Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.properties?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) of each object we can get the dependency *"Name"* and the desired values of the properties *"Version"* and *"Resolved"*. Using a calculated property with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) we can construct a new object.

**Note**, this code assumes you have already used [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) over your Json string and, the object is stored in the `$json` variable.

```
$json.dependencies.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object Name,
    @{
        Name = 'Version'
        Expression = { $_.Value.Version }
    }, @{
        Name = 'Resolved'
        Expression = { $_.Value.Resolved }
    }
```

**Output**

```
Name                        Version Resolved
----                        ------- --------
@babel/runtime              7       https://registry.npmjs.org
@cloud                      2       https://registry.npmjs.org/
@cloudnative/health-connect 2       https://registry.npmjs.org/@***.tgz
```

Comment: Thanks alot guys. I added the "name" into the call and worked as needed.

 @{
   Name = 'Name'
   Expression = { $_.name }
},
 @{
   Name = 'Version'
   Expression = { $_.Value.Version }
}, @{
   Name = 'Resolved'
   Expression = { $_.Value.Resolved }
}

Thank you for your help

Comment: Get the error 

ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the 
operation again.